# How to show posts from category A on category B page?

Tags: terms

On certain user interactions, I want the category page to show products from another category and not show the current category's products. For example - If the current category is `laptop-bags` , I want to remove products with this category and show products having another category `sling-bags`. I have tried to do so using the following code:

```
function check_pre_get_posts($wp_query) {
    
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
    
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => 'sling-bags',
                                        'operator' => 'IN'
                                    )
                                 )
    );
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'check_pre_get_posts');
```

However, the above code leads to the category showing no products at all. How to do this?

Comment: Does it work if you change `$wp_query` to, say, `$my_query`? `$wp_query` is a global variable, and so it might be causing unanticipated issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the following before `$wp_query->set('` :

```
$wp_query->set( 'product_cat', 'sling-bags' );
```